# Popup window without stealing focus from other fullscreen programs

Tags: c++, popup, fullscreen, showwindow

Hi so the title describes it pretty well, I'm currently working on a software that will be installed on a POS system now when an event occurs this program needs to create a popup for the cashier to confirm what my concern is that since this is a separate program from the POS if the POS is fullscreen (not windowed) It will steal focus from the POS thus having to wait 2 seconds while window flashes to black fullscreen pos goes down then popup comes up and then having to restore the POS.

I need to be able to get around this problem of POS minimizing and having the cashier's input as well.

Here is what I'm currently attempting.

```
        // Create the window object
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
                          ClsName, WndName,
                          WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION,
                          200, 120, 200, 320,
                          NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // Find out if the window was created
    if( !hWnd ) // If the window was not created,
            return 0; // stop the application

    // Display the window to the user
    Sleep(10000); //Used so I can open a fullscreen window to test
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You could hire a UX designer to redo it without popups.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your objective, but the MessageBox() function may be what you need, if you haven't tried it yet. See:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx